# I should have the "Fanatic" badge... why do I not?

Tags: support, badges

Either I should definitely have this badge, or I don't understand how the process works: https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/help/badges/55/fanatic

I think that possibly the online indicator doesn't work sometimes. If you look at my profile, it says that I've been online 93 days and only 3 consecutive. But I'm pretty sure I've been online for 100+, all consecutive.

Anyway, I've set this page as my homepage for Firefox to open every time it starts up. And I am completely sure that *every single day* I open up a new Firefox window at least ten times. Even if I only spend a few seconds on this page before I click away, I'm still online here.

Is there anything that can be done about this or do I have to start all over again?

Comment: You're a fanatic in my book.

Comment: xD I just wish there was a way to get the badge. :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've had this happen to me before while trying for this badge both here and on Stack Overflow - just opening the page on startup doesn't seem to count as visiting the site - you actually need to navigate to another page before it will count your visit. Just viewing your profile or a random question once a day (or 10 if you'd prefer) seems to be enough.

Answer (score 3):

"Days" are measured according to UTC, and consequently it's rather easy to "miss" a 24-hour window. Also, certain kinds of login-only activity don't count as accessing the site.

I can see the day you missed, so it's not a problem with the system, just a side-effect of how it works. Unfortunately you'll have to start over. :(

Answer (score 0):

As a wild guess this number and the number you think are off because it's based on server time (UTC maybe?) not local time.

So you might have logged in on two separate days but it was really the same day accounting for the less than 100 count. As an example you visited at 10pm local time one day and 10am local time the next day. This could have been 3am and 3pm server time which would be the same day to the server.

If you visited more than 24 hours apart it's possible you also crossed this threshold and wound up missing a day as well due to the time zone differences. As an example you visited at 1pm local time one day and 3pm local time the next day. This might have been 11pm and 1am server time resulting in you completely missing a day from the servers perspective.

Comment: Well... my timezone is EST. So I don't think that would've been it. I suppose it's possible... but IDK...